# Deleted question stays in my inbox why?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

I decided to delete a question about Mormon policy after it was given lots of down votes. I was intrigued that amid all of the down voting so many regulars were ommenting and debating and editing the question

Nevertheless I can't afford to leave a question hanging out there dropping my rep so I deleted it 
How long until it gets off of my inbox summary? Can I remove it from my inbox?

Comment: I'd guess that the way they've written the inbox software would make it too hard to remove such notifications, and it wouldn't really be very beneficial either.

Answer (score 6):

Deleted posts aren't actually removed from the system. Deleting posts causes them to be hidden from most users and freezes new voting and comments, but the posts are still there and there are a number of things that can be done with them.

- Moderators can still comment. Sometimes this is useful when for whatever reason a post is removed for not fitting the site guidelines and moderators want to leave feedback about that action.
- The post is still owned by you and you can still edit it! This allows you to actually fix whatever issues may have been raised. In the case of a self-delete you can use the time to edit it into shape and then un-delete it when it's ready for public viewing. In the case of moderator or community deleted posts you can edit and then flag them for a moderator to undelete.
- The effect of recent votes will be refunded to your reputation.
- The inbox is a record of recent account activity, and so will continue to show any appropriate messages regarding these posts until other more recent activity pushes it off the stack.